# How to specify a relative path for the jsUnit-ant-script?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ant, build-automation, jsunit

[JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) provides an ant-script with the target 'standalone_test'. This target uses the property url to identify the HTML-site, that executes the tests. These site is checked in, so that everyone should be able after a checkout to execute this tests. This works, but the url-proprty must be set to an absolute path, like `file:///home/user/projects/my-project/path/in/project/jsunit/testRunner.html`. That avoids an automatic start, everyone have too specify a command with the path constructed on his box. Is it possible to pass a relative path/url instead, so that the execution of these tests can be automated? This would be helpful to setup these test in our continuous-integration-system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct the `url` property value using the [built-in Ant `basedir` property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#built-in-props).

For example, if your build script is located in and run from your `/home/user/projects/my-projects` directory you could set your `url` property as:

```
<property
    id="url"
    name="url"
    value="file://${basedir}/path/in/project/jsunit/testRunner.html"/>
```

Comment: Clever idea. Not exactly what I was thinking about, but that should be working.